heuristica upright/roman fonts missing in math mode
On TexLive 2024, I would like to use heuristica in math mode. This works mostly fine, but anything written in a roman font in math mode gets replaced by computer modern. How can I write roman text such as through mathrm{} in heuristica?
I use the invocation of heuristica according to the manual here and use the following MWE
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[osf,scaled=.95]{heuristica} % osf for text, not math
\usepackage{cabin} % sans serif
\usepackage[varqu,varl]{inconsolata} % sans serif typewriter
\usepackage[utopia,bigdelims,vvarbb]{newtxmath} % bb from STIX
\usepackage[cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa} % mathcal
\begin{document}
\title{Some title}
\maketitle
Some text, then some numerals $1232343$ and then some math: $a b c \mathrm{d} D \partial$ 
\end{document}

which gives me:

so clearly anything in roman is replaced by computer modern.
Looking at the logs, it warns about missing fonts, despite me having installed the heuristica package through tlmgr. I get:
LaTeX Font Info:    No file OT1Heuristica-TLF.fd. on input line 11.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/Heuristica-TLF/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 11.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/Heuristica-TLF/m/n' in size <10.5> not avai
lable
(Font)              size <10.95> substituted on input line 11.

Any solutions?

you can try \DeclareSymbolFont{operators}   {T1}{\rmdefault} {m}{n}.

@UlrikeFischer Math accents will be wrong

The problem is that Heuristica is not available in OT1 encoding, which \mathrm relies on.
You can redefine the operators symbol font, but you also need to redefine all accents.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{textcomp} % not needed

\usepackage[osf,scaled=.95]{heuristica} % osf for text, not math
\usepackage{cabin} % sans serif
\usepackage[varqu,varl]{inconsolata} % sans serif typewriter
\usepackage[utopia,bigdelims,vvarbb]{newtxmath} % bb from STIX
\usepackage[cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa} % mathcal

\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{T1}{\rmdefault}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{bold}{T1}{\rmdefault}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\acute}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"01}
\DeclareMathAccent{\grave}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"00}
\DeclareMathAccent{\ddot}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"04}
\DeclareMathAccent{\tilde}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"03}
\DeclareMathAccent{\bar}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"09}
\DeclareMathAccent{\breve}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"08}
\DeclareMathAccent{\check}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"07}
\DeclareMathAccent{\hat}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"02}
\DeclareMathAccent{\dot}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"0A}
\DeclareMathAccent{\mathring}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"06}

\begin{document}

\title{Some title}
\maketitle

$\acute{a}\grave{a}\ddot{a}\tilde{a}\bar{a}\breve{a}\check{a}\hat{a}\dot{a}\mathring{a}$

Some text, then some numerals $1232343$ and then some math: $a b c \mathrm{d} D \partial$ 

{\boldmath
$\acute{a}\grave{a}\ddot{a}\tilde{a}\bar{a}\breve{a}\check{a}\hat{a}\dot{a}\mathring{a}$

Some text, then some numerals $1232343$ and then some math: $a b c \mathrm{d} D \partial$ 
}

\end{document}


Alternatively, use the legacy Utopia.
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[osf,scaled=.95]{heuristica} % osf for text, not math
\usepackage{cabin} % sans serif
\usepackage[varqu,varl]{inconsolata} % sans serif typewriter
\usepackage[utopia,bigdelims,vvarbb]{newtxmath} % bb from STIX
\usepackage[cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa} % mathcal

\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{putmath}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{putmath}{m}{n}{
  <-> s*[0.95] putr7t
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{putmath}{b}{n}{
  <-> s*[0.95] putb7t
}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{OT1}{putmath}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{bold}{OT1}{putmath}{b}{n}

\begin{document}

\title{Some title}
\maketitle

a$\mathrm{a}$

$\acute{a}\grave{a}\ddot{a}\tilde{a}\bar{a}\breve{a}\check{a}\hat{a}\dot{a}\mathring{a}$

Some text, then some numerals $1232343$ and then some math: $a b c \mathrm{d} D \partial$ 

{\boldmath
$\acute{a}\grave{a}\ddot{a}\tilde{a}\bar{a}\breve{a}\check{a}\hat{a}\dot{a}\mathring{a}$

Some text, then some numerals $1232343$ and then some math: $a b c \mathrm{d} D \partial$ 
}

\end{document}



If you can switch to LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, then I'd suggest using the Erewhon Math font with unicode-math for math. It pairs perfectly with the Erewhon text font which in turn is based on Heuristica (it's basically the same font but with some new glyphs etc.). Here's an example:
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Erewhon}[Numbers=OldStyle]
\setsansfont{Cabin}
\setmonofont{inconsolata}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Erewhon Math}
\begin{document}
\title{Some title}
\maketitle
Some text, then some numerals $1232343$ and then some math: $a b c \mathrm{d} D \partial$ 
\end{document}

And the result:

Also, as a matter of fact just replacing \usepackage[osf,scaled=.95]{heuristica} in your original example by \usepackage[osf,scaled=.95]{erewhon} works as well without any other changes in the sources.
